# Is it okay to charge a VRLA with a AGM charger?

Tags: lead-acid

I have a 1000mA [charger](http://www.batteriesplus.com/pc-34553-34553-WK12V1000.aspx) meant for a 10Ah, AGM SLA battery. I picked up a VRLA, which is 17Ah and I am wondering if the charger is OK for it. When I tried to charge it, the green light never came on, even at the peak voltage it reached at 13.5v. I just removed the power when the voltage got to this, and assumed it was charged. If the charger is not suitable, what would be?

Comment: Tell me about the 17 Ah battery. Do you have any more information about it? AGM batteries are a subtype of VRLA batteries. Also I can't open the link to the charger. For how long did the 17 Ah battery charge? Did you hear a hissing sound from it when you decided that it's charged? Did it get warm? Are there any inscriptions on the battery? I've often seen charging instructions printed on them. Can you try recharging the battery with an amperemeter in series to see the current when the voltage reaches 13.5 V?

Comment: In general, I don't see why the charger wouldn't work. As far as I remember, the charging algorithm is pretty much the same for both AGM and gel type VRLA batteries. There could be some minor differences related to cut-off detection for example or the charger could be using just a simple timer or it could wait for the charge current to drop to some value etc.

Comment: The battery was at a Hamfest for 5 dollars and they said that it had just been sitting fully charged for a few years not used, for medical backup. The battery is a panasonic LC-XD1217PG   http://industrial.panasonic.com/www-data/pdf2/ACJ4000/ACJ4000CE66.pdf

Comment: OK, what about other info I asked for? Did you hear a hissing sound when you decided that the battery is full? It is a sign that the battery is overcharged and is venting gas. Next, for how long did you charge the battery? 10 h, 15 h, 20 h, more than 20 hours? Can you measure the current when voltage goes near the 13.5 V? With a 1 A charger, it can take a while for it to charge. Also from what I can see, it should be charged at 13.65 V, so you could have left it not completely charged.

Comment: I barely used the battery, just a 1 amp draw for about 30 min.  until I tried to charge it, and I left it there for 5-6 hours until I got suspicious. I didnt hear any hissing. The battery did not get warm (The transformer sure did though, which is normal) What are inscriptions?

Comment: I simply think that you did not give the battery enough time to charge completely. Do read the document you linked, it has graphs with charge time versus charge current. Also don't assume that you got the battery fully charged! As for term "inscription", look it up in a dictionary, there are many available online for free with much better explanations than the one I could provide.

Answer (score 1):

First of all test the battery with cell discharge tester. A 17AH battery 17 Amps for 1 hour. As the battery kept for years in fully charged condition might have got damaged.